# Truncating an int (or long, or whatever) to a specific size (n bytes), signed and unsigned

Tags: c++

Say I have these two variables:

```
size_t value;
size_t size;
```

And I want to "cast" `value` to the size of `size`.  So if `size` is 4, `value` is casted to be 4 bytes long.  If `size` is 3, `value` is presumably truncated to 3 bytes long, preserving sign (assume a signed int may be loaded into `value` then taken out later to be cast back to signed) and stored in an int/uint depending on sign choice.  Preferably with a method that would work to turn, for example, an unsigned long, or whatever other integral type, to any arbitrary size in bytes along with being signed/unsigned.

Comment: I am not very sure about this, but this should work:
(typeid(size).name()) value

Comment: What does it mean to "truncate" something to "3 bytes long"??? For example, in 2's complement representation any 4-byte signed value is immediately ready to be interpreted as 3-byte value (assuming it fits into the target range). Nothing needs to be changed in the representation. So, what exactly do you mean by "truncate"? Does you platform have a 3-byte integer type? If not, then I can't see what it can possibly mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast to `long` is to preserve the sign, and long is supposed to be at least as big as size_t (though I think that's not actually true in MS compilers).  If it's not true, pick a different signed type as big as size_t and replace the three references to long.

```
size_t casted = size_t(long(value) << (8 * (sizeof(long) - size))) >> (8 * (sizeof(long) - size)));
```

For an unsigned version use size_t instead of long.

This is untested.

Comment: MS is within its rights here. From C99: "The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t **should** not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of signed long int **unless** the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by truncate. If your intent is just to clear the bytes beyond the truncation point to zero, you could probably get away with something like:

```
size_t mask[] = {0x00000000, 0xff000000, 0xffff0000, 0xffffff00, 0xffffffff};
value &= mask[size];
```

So, where `size` is zero, nothing is preserved. Where size is two, only the upper two bytes are preserved.

Obviously, this will depend on the actual *widths* of your data types so is implementation specific. But that's the case anyway since you're casting between `size_t` and other data types - those types are not necessarily compatible.